# Conditional Join in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-filters

Here is what I am doing:
Their is table MEDIA against this their are multiple entries in MEDIA_TAGS table. So based on some user input for media tags I have to fetch the MEDIA table records. So here I have to join the tables MEDIA and MEDIA_TAGS only when their is input for the media tags.

Since it is legacy system I cant modify the existing mapping in hbm file. 
I wanted to know if their is any functionality in Hibernate to add the join on some another table based on certain condition or dynamic input.

Does this possible with predefined filters or is their any way to achieve this in hibernate mapping.  Any pointers on this greatly help me.

Comment: It looks like you are looking to write a simple query adding a where clause with tag names should solve your purpose. You can add named query in hibernate also but you mentioned you cannot change hbm file.

Comment: thanks Sachin for the reply. Yes I can add the named query but the problem is that I cant do modify the existong flow. Is their any alternate to achive it.

Comment: So, looks like you cannot change the hbm files and you cannot even change the flow, then i would suggest to explore options at database level, you can rename existing tables if possible and create views with the same name, inside the views you can add your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used hibernate criteria.createAlias(.. to solve this problem.